# Input with a copy button just like github clone view

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to develop a view with similar tooltip which is on github.[image]

I tried using the css but was not able to create the exact ui.
[image]

My CSS is as follow

```
[tooltip] {
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
}
[tooltip]:hover:after {
  background: #333;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  border-radius: 5px;
  bottom: 26px;
  color: #fff;
  content: attr(tooltip);
  left: 20%;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
[tooltip]:hover:before {
  border: solid;
  border-color: #333 transparent;
  border-width: 6px 6px 0 6px;
  bottom: 20px;
  content: "";
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99;
}
```

Please advise how can I get the same effect.

Comment: Let's see the HTML and/or framework. Not to force Bootstrap (I know Bootstrap isn't the solution to everything) but man, everything about this screams bootstrap

Comment: Also, the neat thing about the web is that you can see the code for pretty much everything. Just right click "inspect element" in Chrome and in the "Styles" tab you can see all of the CSS applied to a particular element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what is worth if you consider bootstrap, similar, or a partial bootstrap installation or related classes, you can achieve this like this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-push-4 martop50">
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">https://</span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Amount (to the nearest dollar)">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-clipboard" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Copy to clipboard"></i></span>
        </div>
        <span class="download-btn"><button class="btn btn-sm" ><i class="fa fa-download"></i></button></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.martop50{
    margin-top:50px;
}
.download-btn{
    display:inline;
    float: left;
    margin: 0px 2px;
}

.btn-group-sm>.btn, .btn-sm {
    padding: 7px 12px;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

.input-group {
    position: relative;
    display: table;
    border-collapse: separate;
    width: 88%;
    float: left;
}
```

**Tooltip JQUERY**

```
$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
})
```

The rest of your work would be practically cosmetics and replacing the http:// with a dropdown. That should be fairly easy for you to do.

Here is the [**DEMO**](http://codepen.io/LOTUSMS/pen/YwVmaJ)

Answer (score 1):

Try removing , adjusting `left:20%` , also possibly `padding: 5px 15px;` at `[tooltip]:hover:after`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a tooltip that opens downwards.

```css
[tooltip] {
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted rgba(0,0,0,.21);
}
[tooltip]:hover {
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
}
[tooltip]:hover:after {
  background: #333;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  border-radius: 5px;
  top: calc(100% + 3px);
  color: #fff;
  content: attr(tooltip);
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  padding: 5px 15px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99;
  white-space: nowrap;
  box-sizing: border-box; 
 
}
[tooltip]:hover:before {
  border: solid;
  border-color: transparent transparent rgba(0,0,0,.8);
  border-width: 6px;
  bottom: -3px;
  left: calc(50% - 3px);
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99;
 }
```

```html
<div tooltip="I am tooltip">
  I am some content.
</div>
<hr>
Let's see a tooltip on an <span tooltip="Hey, I'm a tooltip, too!">inline element.</span>
```

However, the way to go here is to have tooltip arguments on the html element and build specific positioning rules for your alignment params (You probably want to have `tooltip-position` attribute set to `top|bottom|left|right` and have specific CSS for each case). For example:

```
[tooltip][tooltip-position="bottom"]:hover:after { /*code here*/ }
```

From the looks of it, considering the required coding effort and your apparent CSS knowledge, using a library might save you some time. Possible candidates:

- [Bootstrap Tooltip](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_tooltip.asp)
- [jQuery tootip](https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/)
- [tooltipster](http://iamceege.github.io/tooltipster/)
- [qtip2](http://qtip2.com/)
- [tipped](http://projects.nickstakenburg.com/tipped)
- [tooltipsy](http://tooltipsy.com/)

These are only a few examples, I'm not endorsing any of them and there are plenty of others. You should research this yourself and decide based on your projects' needs.